# Learning C# quickly

Tags: c#, .net

I just got a position at a big, well-known C#/.NET company. The thing is that I don't know any C# or .NET at all (they know that) and I want to learn as much as I can before I start, to not waste time (and money).

How do I learn C#/.NET quickly and efficiently? Resources? Great tutorials? Videos?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I have a couple of years experience with Java. So I am not new to programming - just new to .NET.

UPDATE:
Thank you for all your replies. I have ordered "Essential C# 4.0" and until then, I will go through some of the guides / tutorials and the general documentation at MSDN.

Comment: Do you have any programming experience at all?

Comment: You know Java already? s/toString/ToString and you're done.

Comment: http://norvig.com/21-days.html it might help

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Download Visual Studio Express (its free and comes with everything you need to get started) if you don't have any of the tools already and start by trying to accomplish something. Do a tutorial or three, but then go for a goal and build a project that does something. You may spend the next week searching non-stop on Google but hey - isn't that programming?

This will get your feet wet, get you familiar with the IDE and working with a database in C#, and will teach you how to solve problems in C# better than any set of videos or tutorials ever could.

The following are a list of commonly accepted videos and tutorials that may help though:

- Illustrated C#: [http://www.amazon.com/Illustrated-2010-Experts-Voice-NET/dp/143023282X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/143023282X) (While I was going through the C# Fundamentals videos the Illustrated C# book became extremely handy as a companion guide.)
- C# Fundamentals at http://pluralsight.com (Also, depending on what you're going to be doing with C# (ie. ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF, WCF, etc.) you'll find that Pluralsight's website has a ridiculous amount of .NET related video training.)
- [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library)
- [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)
- [Learning Style](http://www.learning-styles-online.com/inventory/)
- [Learn VisualStudio.NET](http://www.learnvisualstudio.net/)
- http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321694694
- http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1590598849
- [CLR via C#](http://rcm.amazon.com/e/cm?lt1=_blank&bc1=000000&IS2=1&bg1=FFFFFF&fc1=000000&lc1=0000FF&t=alwaysbepassi-20&o=1&p=8&l=as4&m=amazon&f=ifr&ref=ss_til&asins=0735627045)

Comment: +1. Programmers learn by doing. For example, I only truly learned OOP and MVVM and other architectures/patterns by cutting my teeth on some real projects, writing some truly awful code, gradually improving on it, running up against various limits and corners that my initial rookie practices caused me to paint myself into, and finally realizing the usefulness of such patterns.

Comment: Though a little dated now I still recommend [C# for Java Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228358.aspx).